# Xamarin.Forms layout equivalent to FrameLayout

Tags: android, xaml, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Just a beginner question about what is the equivalent to FrameLayout (Android) in Xamarin.Forms?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

FrameLayout is a control that is designed to contain a single child but can optionally have multiple children that are controlled with gravity or what works similar to zindex.

I don't think there is a direct map from xamarin.Forms to Framelayout.

if your just looking for a page level container for a single control there is:

- **Frame**-An element containing a single child, with some framing options. Frame have a default Xamarin.Forms.Layout.Padding of 20.
- **ScrollView**-An element capable of scrolling if it's Content requires.

If your looking for a Multiple Item Container the options are:

- **Grid** -A layout containing views arranged in rows and columns.
- **RelativeLayout** -A Layout that uses Constraints to layout its children.
- **StackLayout** - A Layout that positions child elements in a single line which can be oriented vertically or horizontally. This layout will set the child bounds automatically during a layout cycle. User assigned bounds will be overwritten and thus should not be set on a child element by the user.

see:https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/controls/layouts/

However none of these support the Z-Index like ability of FrameLayout the best option at the moment is a Grid with a single element. The children will layout from back to front in the order they are in the Grids.Children stack.

Comment: You can use RaiseChild and LowerChild to (sort of) affect the Z-Index.